# Vuetify clickable card with button

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a clickable `v-card` that acts as a link due to its `to` prop. The card contains a button that is clickable as well. Something like this:

```html
<v-card :to="{ name: 'MyView' }">
  <v-btn @click.stop="myAction"></v-btn>
  ... other elements ...
</v-card>
```

Now when clicking the button inside the card, the button's click handler (`myAction`) is executed but the link is followed as well. How can I change this to have only the click handler executed when the button is clicked?

Comment: I'd say that `@click.stop.prevent` should do it yeah. Maybe try `@click.native` too https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `prevent` should be used instead.
Because the browser's default action for the link should be stopped.

```html
<v-card :to="{ name: 'MyView' }">
  <v-btn @click.prevent="myAction">something</v-btn>
  ... other elements ...
</v-card>
```